# Django and Pandas - Create an object from a Foreying Key field

Tags: python, django, pandas

I am trying to create objects importing data from an excel with pandas, than creating objects with django.

But i am geting this error message:

```
Name: ticker, dtype: object
Asset matching query does not exist.
Asset matching query does not exist.
Asset matching query does not exist.
...
```

My Models

```
class Asset(models.Model):
    ticker = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)


class Transaction(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    OrderChoices = (
        ('Buy', 'Buy'),
        ('Sell', 'Sell'),
    )
    date =  models.DateField(("Date"), default=date.today)
    order = models.CharField(max_length = 8, choices = OrderChoices) 
    asset = models.ForeignKey(Asset, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=1)
    shares_amount = models.FloatField()
    share_cost = models.FloatField()
```

And here is my updater file code:

```
class Command(BaseCommand):

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        excel_file = "orders.xlsx"
        df_2 = pd.read_excel(excel_file)
        df_2 = df_2[['Date(UTC)','Pair', 'Type', 'Order Amount', 'AvgTrading Price']]
        df_2.columns = ['date', 'ticker', 'order', 'shares_amount','share_cost']
        df_2['date'] = df_2['date'].str[:9]
        df_2['ticker'] = df_2['ticker'].str.replace('USDT', '')
        df_2['order'] = df_2['order'].str.replace('BUY', 'Buy')
        print(df_2['ticker'])
        
        for index, row in df_2.iterrows():
            try:
                Transaction.objects.create(
                    date =  datetime.date.today(),
                    order = df_2['order'] ,
                    asset = Asset.objects.get(ticker = df_2['ticker']),
                    shares_amount = df_2['shares_amount'],
                    share_cost_brl = df_2['share_cost'],
                )
            except Exception as e:
                print(f' Key Exception - {e}')
                pass
```

When i try to `print(df_2['ticker'])`, i get as result a list with id(from pandas index) and ticker

```
0     BNB
1    LINK
2     XMR
3     DOT
4    AVAX
5    LUNA
6     SOL
7     ETH
8     BTC
```

i just added to the code to get the list of assets

```
queryset = Asset.objects.values_list("ticker")
df = pd.DataFrame(list(queryset), columns=["ticker"]) 
print(df)
```

the result:

```
   ticker
0     XRP
1     XMR
2     VET
3    USDT
4     STX
5     SOL
...
17    ETH
18    DOT
19    CRO
20    BTC
21    BNB
22   AVAX
23   ATOM
24    ADA
25   AAVE
26  1INCH
```

Comment: What exactly `print(df_2['asset'])` prints?

Comment: Hi @BartoszStasiak, thanks for the answer, just added the output of `print(df_2['asset'])`

Comment: Hi @BartoszStasiak .  Found the error, it was how to get the single value of the field, instead of using `df_2['field']` was getting the index and field, to get only the field without index i should use `df_2.loc[index]['field']`

Comment: Ow  cool! I will update my answer so it will not misguide anyone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the error, it was how to get the single value of the field, instead of using `df_2['field']` was getting the index and field, to get only the field without index i should use `df_2.loc[index]['field']`

Also i did some workaround to get the `asset_id` instead of `asset`

How it get in the end:

```
for index, row in df_2.iterrows():
            try:
                Transaction.objects.create(
                    date =  datetime.date.today(),
                    order = df_2.loc[index]['order'] ,
                    asset_id = df_3.loc[index]['id'],
                    shares_amount = df_2.loc[index]['shares_amount'],
                    share_cost_brl = df_2.loc[index]['share_cost_usd'],
                )
            except Exception as e:
                print(f' Key Exception - {e}')
                pass
```

And here is the workaround to get the id, don`t know if is the best solution, but i decided to go this way to make object creation more simple:

```
# changed the index of df_2
df_2['order'] = df_2['order'].str.replace('BUY', 'Buy')
df_2 = df_2.set_index('ticker')

# got the assets from the django app with id, set the ticker as index also and merged both tables using the ticker as index
queryset = Asset.objects.values_list('id', "ticker")
df = pd.DataFrame(list(queryset), columns=['id',"ticker"]) 
df = df.set_index('ticker')
# print(df)
df_3 = df_2.merge(df, left_on="ticker",right_on="ticker",how='inner').set_axis(df_2.index)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Pandas, but for  `asset = Asset.objects.get(ticker = df_2['asset']),` to work you need to access single ticker value out of it.

I guess it will be something like:

```
 asset = Asset.objects.get(ticker=df_2[row_idx]['column_name'])
```

for example:

```
asset = Asset.objects.get(ticker=df_2[0]['asset'])
```

Comment: Thanks, i tried and got this error: `Name: asset, dtype: object`
 `Key Exception - 'ticker'`, than i tried `Asset.objects.get(ticker = df_2['asset'][0]), and got a diferent error :) `The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().`

Comment: `print(df_2['asset'][0])` prints BNB

Comment: How about `df_2['asset'][0].item()`?

Comment: `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'item'`

Comment: Ooook... Last try. `df_2['asset'].get_values()[0]` If that doesn't work then I need to read Pandas docs first

Comment: `AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'get_values'`

Comment: How about `df_2['asset'].values[0]` then?

Comment: Try also `df_2['asset'].array[0]` . As I said. I'm not familiar with Pandas. You need to find a way to access ticker value `df_2['asset']` and it will work

Comment: thanks, that shows the first value, yes, i will try somethings here, i just added to the question pandas reading the Model table, the field in the table is called ticker, i will update df2 to see if it works... thanks for the effort

Comment: I updated my answer then. If it solves your issue then you can mark it as accepted. If not then we can try to figure out other things in chat. Good luck!

Comment: got this error `The truth value of a Series is ambiguous.`

Comment: I don't understand why it can't make comparison there. What if you extract this value first to some variable and then use it in Asset.objects.get()?. I Updated my answer with example